# trying to convert cartesian coordinates to polar coordinates but NOT WORKING

Tags: c

**this is what I have so far. I'm supposed to get the quadrant for (x,y), the radius, and the angle.  I don't have any errors but when i put 1 in for x and 1 in for y it gives me

```
quadrant:0.000000 radius:.785398 angle:0.0000000**
```

If you see any errors please let me know. I would greatly appreciate it!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int get_quadrant(double, double);
double get_radius(double, double);
double get_angle(double, double);
void show_info(int, double, double);

int main() {
  double X, Y, rad, theta;
  int quad;
  printf("input the value for the x coordinate: \n");
  scanf("%f", &X);
  printf("input the value for the y coordinate: \n");
  scanf("%f", &Y);
  quad = get_quadrant(X, Y);
  rad = get_radius(X, Y);
  theta = get_angle(X, Y);
  show_info(quad, rad, theta);
  return 0;
}

int get_quadrant(double X, double Y) {
  int quadrant;
  if (X > 0 && Y > 0) {
    quadrant == 1;
    return quadrant;
  }

  else if (X < 0 && Y > 0) {
    quadrant == 2;
    return quadrant;
  }

  else if (X < 0 && Y < 0) {
    quadrant = 3;
    return quadrant;
  }

  else if (X > 0 && Y < 0) {
    quadrant = 4;
    return quadrant;
  }
}

double get_radius(double X, double Y) {
  double r;
  r = sqrt((X) * (X) + (Y) * (Y));
}

double get_angle(double X, double Y) {
  double angle;
  angle = atan(Y / X);
}

void show_info(int quad, double rad, double theta) {
  printf("quadrant: %f  radius:  %f    angle:  %f.\n", quad, rad, theta);
}
```

Comment: Start by compiling with warnings enabled (gcc: `-Wall -Wextra` ; MSVC: `/W3`) and fix all of them.

Comment: tswift1998, `function get_radius()` and `get_angle()` lack a _return_ values.  Save time.  Enable all warnings.

Comment: Never use atan(x/y). Use atan2 instead.

Answer (score 0):

You actually are comparing values instead of assigning them in the `get_quadrant` functions, you can replace `==` by `=` in the first and second sections. Also, in the `get_radius` function, r is the squared value of the real radius.
Don't forget to add the return values of non-void functions